# Concatenate separate fields to date

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do you concatenate in this query?

SQL

```
SELECT
  eventscheduling.eventID,
  event.eventName,
  event.description,
  sponsorCLUB.Organization,
  department.Dname,
  eventscheduling.smonth,
  eventscheduling.sdate, 
  eventscheduling.syear,
  eventscheduling.tHour,
  eventscheduling.tMinute,
  eventscheduling.tAmPm, 
  eventscheduling.venue,
  eventscheduling.representative 
FROM eventscheduling, event, department, sponsorCLUB
WHERE event.eventID=eventscheduling.eventID and 
  sponsorCLUB.sponsorID=eventscheduling.sponsorID and
  department.DeptID=sponsorCLUB.DeptID and 
  eventscheduling.eventID='"+txtsearch.getText()+"'";
```

Code

```
String sql="select eventscheduling.eventID, event.eventName, event.description,
 sponsorCLUB.Organization, department.Dname, eventscheduling.smonth, eventscheduling.sdate, 
eventscheduling.syear, eventscheduling.tHour, eventscheduling.tMinute, eventscheduling.tAmPm, 
eventscheduling.venue, eventscheduling.representative from eventscheduling, event, department, 
sponsorCLUB where event.eventID=eventscheduling.eventID and 
sponsorCLUB.sponsorID=eventscheduling.sponsorID and department.DeptID=sponsorCLUB.DeptID and 
eventscheduling.eventID='"+txtsearch.getText()+"'";
```

I'd like `smonth`, `sdate` and `syear` to be combined into a Date.

Comment: how do you want the result to look and what's your database?

Comment: What is the programming language that sets this variable?

Answer (score 1):

DateSerial can be used to create a single date from constituent parts -
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateserial.php

```
SELECT
  DateSerial(eventscheduling.syear,
             eventscheduling.smonth,
             eventscheduling.sdate) as eventschedulingdate
```

BTW you have a SQL injection vulnerability by allowing user input to be directly added to a SQL query.